# Error "Argument Google Apps" Script UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, urlfetch

i'm currently trying to input data from excel to google form through google script. i've used the code i learnt from youtube and it worked to create the final url needed to complete the filling form.

here's the code

```
function autoEntry() {
 
  var wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17O3MhqcWIcdq3SlaR-cdr2Y6t3Mr1EWJ9E6AWh_qamo/edit?pli=1#gid=0');
  var wrkSht = wrkBk.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var formURL = ""
  var formData = ""

  var JenisKelamin = ""
  var Usia = ""
  var PendidikanTerakhir = ""
  var Pekerjaan = ""
  var Penghasilan = ""
  var TransaksiSering = ""
  var LamaGuna = ""
  var Frekuensi = ""
  var Informasi = ""
  var Aplikasi = ""
  var X11 = ""
  var X12 = ""
  var X13 = ""
  var X14 = ""
  var X15 = ""
  var X16 = ""
  var X21 = ""
  var X22 = ""
  var X23 = ""
  var X24 = ""
  var X25 = ""
  var X26 = ""
  var Y1 = ""
  var Y2 = ""
  var Y3 = ""
  var Y4 = ""
  var Y5 = ""
  var Y6 = ""
  var Y7 = ""

  var noOfRows = 409;

  for (i=2;i<=noOfRows;i++)
  {
    JenisKelamin = wrkSht.getRange("A"+i).getDisplayValue();
    Usia = wrkSht.getRange("B"+i).getDisplayValue();
    PendidikanTerakhir = wrkSht.getRange("C"+i).getDisplayValue();
    Pekerjaan = wrkSht.getRange("D"+i).getDisplayValue();
    Penghasilan = wrkSht.getRange("E"+i).getDisplayValue();
    TransaksiSering = wrkSht.getRange("F"+i).getDisplayValue();
    LamaGuna = wrkSht.getRange("G"+i).getDisplayValue();
    Frekuensi = wrkSht.getRange("H"+i).getDisplayValue();
    Informasi = wrkSht.getRange("I"+i).getDisplayValue();
    Aplikasi = wrkSht.getRange("J"+i).getDisplayValue();
    X11 = wrkSht.getRange("K"+i).getDisplayValue();
    X12 = wrkSht.getRange("L"+i).getDisplayValue();
    X13 = wrkSht.getRange("M"+i).getDisplayValue();
    X14 = wrkSht.getRange("N"+i).getDisplayValue();
    X15 = wrkSht.getRange("O"+i).getDisplayValue();
    X16 = wrkSht.getRange("P"+i).getDisplayValue();
    X21 = wrkSht.getRange("Q"+i).getDisplayValue();
    X22 = wrkSht.getRange("R"+i).getDisplayValue();
    X23 = wrkSht.getRange("S"+i).getDisplayValue();
    X24 = wrkSht.getRange("T"+i).getDisplayValue();
    X25 = wrkSht.getRange("U"+i).getDisplayValue();
    X26 = wrkSht.getRange("V"+i).getDisplayValue();
    Y1 = wrkSht.getRange("W"+i).getDisplayValue();
    Y2 = wrkSht.getRange("X"+i).getDisplayValue();
    Y3 = wrkSht.getRange("Y"+i).getDisplayValue();
    Y4 = wrkSht.getRange("Z"+i).getDisplayValue();
    Y5 = wrkSht.getRange("AA"+i).getDisplayValue();
    Y6 = wrkSht.getRange("AB"+i).getDisplayValue();
    Y7 = wrkSht.getRange("AC"+i).getDisplayValue();

    formURL = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSchR5C98u79wi42-efVxKv3_epKSdpFklX1bMzC1dJbS2nmOQ/formResponse?&pageHistory=0,1,2,3"
    formData = "&entry.648709615="+ JenisKelamin + "&entry.2126511656=" + Usia + "&entry.26299417=" + PendidikanTerakhir + "&entry.1006337461=" + Pekerjaan + "&entry.605483759=" + Penghasilan + "&entry.696686468=" + TransaksiSering + "&entry.431572043=" + LamaGuna + "&entry.1848702501=" + Frekuensi + "&entry.2074200768=" + Informasi + "&entry.2141675646=" + Aplikasi + "&entry.1532148781=" + X11 + "&entry.986181026=" + X12 + "&entry.1899553718=" + X13 + "&entry.831653079=" + X14 + "&entry.2026432620=" + X15 + "&entry.77763837=" + X16 + "&entry.1791093619=" + X21 + "&entry.576102553=" + X22 + "&entry.1775027265=" + X23 + "&entry.601678288=" + X24 + "&entry.1603179306=" + X25 + "&entry.636968087=" + X26 + "&entry.812416152=" + Y1 + "&entry.1349313252=" + Y2 + "&entry.724123780=" + Y3 + "&entry.387033357=" + Y4 + "&entry.1193680077=" + Y5 + "&entry.1060716965=" + Y6 + "&entry.618773433=" + Y7 +""

    var finalURL = formURL + formData

    var options = {
      "method" : "post"
    };

    UrlFetchApp.fetch(finalURL, options);
  }

}
```

But when its trying to fetch the url, it got an error.

[Execution log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J6Ve.png)

I tried using on anonymous mode to see if maybe the problem is when trying to fill the form, and it doesn't work because it is an open google form.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: About the error of `Invalid argument`, although I'm not sure about your values, how about trying to use the URL encode as follows? Please modify from `UrlFetchApp.fetch(finalURL, options);` to `UrlFetchApp.fetch(encodeURI(finalURL), options);`? ([encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)) If an error occurs, please try to use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). But, if I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: About `It worked, Thank you so much`, welcome and I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.